Buck Converter IC with 3.5V Minimum Input: Will It Work Reliably with a LiPo Battery for an ESP32-S3?
I need a buck converter for an ESP32-S3 with a wide input voltage range that can support USB power (5V), LiPo battery (3.5V), or solar panel power (up to 24V) and provide a 2.5A output to power Wi-Fi and a P10 LED panel.
I decided to use this buck IC:
Link to datasheet
(I found this to be the best option, though it requires more components.)
This IC has a minimum input voltage of 3.5V. If I use only a LiPo battery, what will happen when the battery voltage drops below 3.8V?
Or, put differently: if the IC’s minimum input voltage is 3.5V, down to what voltage from a LiPo battery will the ESP32 still receive sufficient power?
It seems that the input voltage range of 3.5V to 28V might not be ideal for powering my system solely from a LiPo battery.

I suspect that questions like this are more suited for chat, since this is border line off-topic, particularly "I can't find part x in country y" kind of concerns.

You can try the TI WEBENCH-CIRCUIT-DESIGNER tool. It should be able to find you a good converter.
An example would be the

LM65645
TLVM13640
Those are the cheapest.
What is good about TI WEBENCH is that it gives you all the components' values, layout, etc, even performance data.
You should be also able to find a converter at Analog but they are generally more expensive. I would recommend TI for this application.


There's two problems with TI though: non-existing technical support and subpar EMC characteristics. If the OP is fine with that, then yeah TI has lots of cheap ****, some that you might even get past EMC testing. My general experience is however "it was cheap but now we failed the $10k EMC test"... so not very cheap at all.

I never had issues with the EMC tests. We use TI-Converters exclusively.
But the support is bad.

I've used them back and forth since the first generation "simple switcher" back when it was National Semi. Some parts are ok, some are rotten eggs and you can't know in advance which one the next part you found happens to be. I've gotten some of these through MIL EMC testing, while others fail spectacularly just lying on your desk jamming nearby RF. And no it's not because of layout - using pretty much identical layout but switching to an LT part instead very often fixes all problems. If TI had actual tech support it would be less of a concern, but they don't, so you are on your own.
